# Why rviz crash when using robot_upstart?

Tags: ros, arduino, rviz, ros-melodic, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, really need some help in getting rviz to work with robot_upstart. I'll try to describe the issue and what I have tried as detailed as possible.

1. Requirement:

I would like to make an integrated roslaunch that start when the robot computer boot/turned on. My integrated roslaunch file includes these ROS nodes:

- Arduino rosserial node (USB connected)
- HMI node that is based on QT (touchscreen HDMI connected)
- Hokuyo LiDAR using urg_node (USB connected)
- Rviz node which received data from hokuyo lidar for Lidar reading
- QR code reading node (using USB Webcam)

2. Specifications:

- ROS Melodic
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Jetson Xavier AGX
- Arduino Due

3. Issue

When I boot up the robot computer, every node except for rviz working as I intended. Note that I already tested the roslaunch before implementing the robot_upstart and the rviz node CAN work with the lidar. It can display live update from lidar reading.
I used multiple steps and tutorial to implement robot_upstart in the robot computer.

First, I follow the step from this tutorial https://roboticsbackend.com/make-ros-launch-start-on-boot-with-robot_upstart/ . I used this command to install my roslaunch to become:

```
rosrun robot_upstart install agv_slam/launch/agv_main.launch --job agv_uia  --symlink
```

However, this only allow my ros nodes to be run in the background only. So no display at all from my HMI node and camera node. I then tried these steps: https://github.com/Khalaf90/robot_upstart and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67859236/ros-rviz-issues-when-starting-using-robot-startup. This tutorial basically ask me to modified my roslaunch service which is named as agv_uia and this service file in produced from the robot_upstart command. I did as the tutorial did and below is my service file:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/YourServiceName.service
```

This is the agv_uia.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description="bringup agv_uia"
After=network.target
After=display_manager.service
Wants=display_manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority"
Environment="/home/mic-710aix"
Environment="XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/home/mic-710aix/catkin_ws/tmp"
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/agv_uia-start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Even when I edited this, RVIZ still can't worked with robot_startup. The error that I got was:

```
rviz crashed with SIGABRT in__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402496/why-rviz-crash-when-using-robot_upstart?/) by [dual-swordsman](https://answers.ros.org/users/40035/dual-swordsman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2022-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I just want to update that I already solved this. Apparently, there is a syntax error for home environment. Below is a working service file to implement robot upstart with launch file, QT generated interface and RVIZ.

```
[Unit]
Description="bringup agv_uia"
After=network.target
After=display_manager.service
Wants=display_manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority"
Environment="HOME=/home/mic-710aix"
Environment="XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/home/mic-710aix/catkin_ws/tmp"
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/agv_uia-start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

Originally posted by [dual-swordsman](https://answers.ros.org/users/40035/dual-swordsman/) with karma: 17 on 2022-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0